# Why does this generic method call the base class method, not the derived class method?

Tags: c#, generics

For the following code:

```
class B
{
    public String G() { return "B.G()"; }
}

class D : B
{
    public String G() { return "D.G()"; }
}

class TestCompile
{
    private static String TestG<T>(T b) where T: B 
    {
        return b.G();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestG(new D());
    }
}
```

The result is `B.G()`, whereas the result of similar C++ code would be `D.G()`.

Why is there this difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# generics are compiled only once: at the time the generic is compiled. (Think about it: C# lets you use `List<T>` without seeing its implementation.)  Here, it sees from the `where T: B` clause that the parameter is a `B`, so it calls `B.G`.

C++ templates are compiled each time they are invoked. When you type `TestG<D>()`, a brand new copy of `TestG` is compiled with `T = D`. At invocation time, the compiler sees that `D` has its own `G` method and calls it.

The C++ equivalent of the C# generic would be

```
template<typename T>
string TestG(T t)
{
    B& b = static_cast<B&>(t); // force `t` into a `B`
    return b.G();
}
```

The remarks of others regarding the use of `virtual` apply equally to C# and C++. I'm just explaining why C++ behaves differently from C#.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Nice explanation.

Comment: However, your explanation suggests that the generic does not work in C#, because the method needs to be instantiated for each type of T.  Or in another word, C# wrongly cast D to B before calling the generic method.

Comment: C# Doesn't cast `D` to `B` it puts a reference to `D` in a var with type `B`. if you put the same reference in a var with type `D` it will call `G` on `D`

Comment: I do not understand here: why "it puts a reference to D in a var with type B" not "a reference to D in a var with type D"? According to C# specification: "where T : <base class name>: The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.", "where T: B" is not an instantiation, so that I am expecting a reference of D here.

Comment: This seems a C# bug because java behaves the same way as C++.  I can only post my java code in 3 hours, but it is easy enough.

Comment: Actually, java behaves the same as C#, by using type erasure. The difference between java and C# is that in java, all methods are `virtual` by default. Therefore, it's as if the original code had said `virtual public String G() {...}`, at which point we are in the cases discussed by other answers.

Answer (score 9):

Use the override keyword:

```
class B
{
    public virtual String G() { return "B.G()"; }
}

class D : B
{
    public override String G() { return "D.G()"; }
}
```

Without the override keyword, the inherited method doesn't replace the base one.

Without override:

```
D obj = new D();
obj.G(); // "D.G()"
((B)obj).G(); // "B.G()"
```

With override:

```
D obj = new D();
obj.G(); // "D.G()"
((B)obj).G(); // "D.G()"
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use generic to acheive virtual function call at compile time.  In my original C++ code D::G() effectively overrides B::G() without requiring the virtual keyword. If I can write a preprocessor which always cast each object to its original type in background, namely, changing "TestG((B) new D());" to "TestG((D)((B) new D()));" by the preprocessor, I no longer need the dynamic binding thru v-table for method overriding.

Comment: Well, what is the point of using C# if you're not doing it the C# way? :p

Comment: I was surprised by C# behavior: "where T: B" seems to be an instantiation in C++ term.  If this is the case, I fail to see the need for generic in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 3):

Becuase you've neglected to mark `B.G` as `virtual`, and `D.G` as `override`.

You got this compiler warning:

> CS0108: 'D.G()' hides inherited member 'B.G()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

but you chose to ignore it. I would expect better from a C++ developer! :)

Comment: adding a `new` doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @the_ajp I'm not suggesting it would. I was quoting the compiler output, hence the 'quote' formatting. You'll notice I give the actual solution in my first line.

Comment: By the way, I intentionally allow D.G() to hide B.G(), still I see B.G() get called.

Comment: Sometimes, when actual results differ from expected results, the appropriate corrective action is to change your expectations. C# isn't C++; if you expect it to be C++, you're going to be surprised. If you want to understand the way C# handles method resolution with generics and inheritance, I would suggest reading a good book **on C#**, rather than trying to apply your knowledge of C++ templates. The differences between generics and templates are significant enough that knowledge of one is useful only at the most conceptual level (if that) when understanding the other.

Comment: After reading some web site and C# spec, I still could not see this is the expected behavior in C#, unless "where T: B" actually means to instantiate TestG<B>, which seems to be AGAINST C# spec.  If this is the case, I could see that C# generic is not useful in most cases C++ template is used.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/a/2649546 and links therefrom of use. But if you *really* think "It seems that C# generic implementation has a bug" is a remotely probable explanation for the difference between your expectation and reality, this isn't going to be a productive process.

Comment: The reason I think that it is a bug of C# because java has the same behavior as C++.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the parameter `b` is in a `B` type ref. if you cast `b` to `D` it'll call the function on `D`.

Comment: According to C# documentation, in "private static String TestG<T>(T b) where T: B", "B" is only the base class, not the instanciation class.  It seems that C# generic implementation has a bug.